# How to make awk system variables ”CONVERT“ and "IGNORECASE" work?

Tags: awk

I'm learning awk. I'm writing the code as:

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;print match("gridsphere",/D/)}'
```

I expect this code to print four, but it print zero.

And this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{data[10.15]="1200";CONVERT="%d";printf("<%s>",data[10.15])}'
```

I expect this code to print `<>` but it prints `<1200>`.

My question is why the variables `IGNORECASE` and `CONVERT` do not work.

My system is Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your efforts. Please do add sample of input and expected output also in your question to make it more clear, thank you

Comment: What output you get when you do `awk --version`?

Answer (score 2):

For your first item (IGNORECASE) check whether your Ubuntu system is using gawk (the GNU implementation of awk) or mawk (a different, more traditional implementation). Ubuntu supports installing either or both, and if both, which one is used for the name `awk` is controlled by the 'alternatives' package; check `update-alternatives --display awk`. IGNORECASE is a gawk extension and does not work in mawk (i.e. it's just a user variable with no special meaning).

> `awk 'BEGIN{data[10.15]="1200";CONVERT="%d";printf("<%s>",data[10.15])}'`
>
> I expect this code print `<>` but it print `<1200>`.

(corrected) **Almost.** CONVERT is not an awk 'system' variable (POSIX calls these 'special' variables and both gawk and mawk documentation call them 'built-in' or 'predefined'). **CONVFMT** is special/built-in, and affects conversions from noninteger number to string other than as a direct operand of `print` -- like your index/subscript; note specifying a *string* is NOT affected because that isn't doing conversion:

```
$ mawk 'BEGIN{data[10.15]="X";CONVFMT="%d";print "<"data[10.15]">";print "<"data["10.15"]">"}'
<>
<X>
$ gawk 'BEGIN{data[10.15]="X";CONVFMT="%d";print "<"data[10.15]">";print "<"data["10.15"]">"}'
<>
<X>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. My first question is solved. I checked my awk of computer throgh `update-alternatives --display awk` your suggest. its out put is `mawk`. I have been understand my fault. But the second question, I mean why the ***CONVERT*** does't work for ***10.15*** in `data[10.15]`, Shouldn't CONVERT work on all numbers?And thanks for you answer.

Comment: AH! you were after the index/subscript; I missed that. **CONVFMT** (_not_ CONVERT) does affect that. Corrected.